# Intel xdk $.getJson fail on apk

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, apk, intel-xdk

I'm developing an app with Intel xdk, and i have to make a json request to a website.
It works if i try the app from the xdk emulator and if i try with the app preview but i if build the apk file, install it, then the request fail.

This is the example call:

```
$.getJSON("http://time.jsontest.com", function(data){
alert(data);});
```

And this is the response:

```
GET http://time.jsontest.com/ 404 (Not Found)
```

My device is obviously connected.

In my index.html i have included "intelxdk.js" and "xhr.js" as [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps) says

Comment: Ok, solved.I had to add `<access origin="*" />` to the config.xml file
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution.  If possible, it would be very helpful to submit is an answer, rather than just a comment, so it's easier for others to find in the future, and it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved.I had to add `<access origin="*" />` to the config.xml file.
More info here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html